# scrapy - scraping a field on next page and then returning to old page

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to scrape data from the site: http://www.consumercomplaints.in/?search=ecom-express# 
I am hoping my request is quite simple and straightforward for the more experienced Scrapy users out there.

Problem: I am trying to scrape data for each review.By data,**I mean main title,subtitle ,username,date and review. ** But what i am not able to get the review ,since for review what i want is to goto the link embedded with the main title and then get the whole review not the brief one on the first page and do this for each review.

My spider class:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from consumercomplaint.items import ConsumercomplaintItem

class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "consumer"
    allowed_domains = ["http://www.consumercomplaints.in"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.consumercomplaints.in/?search=ecom-express&page=11"]

def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    titles = hxs.select('//table[@width="100%"]')
    print titles
    items = []
    del(titles[0])
    for i in titles:
        item = ConsumercomplaintItem()
        item ["maintitle"] = i.select('.//a[1]//text()').extract()
        item ["username"] = i.select('.//td[@class="small"]//a[2]/text()').extract()
        item["date"]=i.select('.//td[@class="small"]/text()').extract()
        item["subtitle"]=i.select('.//td[@class="compl-text"]/div/b[1]/text()').extract()
        item["complaint"]=i.select('.//td[@class="compl-text"]/div/text()').extract()
        items.append(item)
    return items
```

My item class:

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class ConsumercomplaintItem(Item):
    maintitle = Field()
    username = Field()
    date = Field()
    subtitle = Field()
    complaint = Field()
```

Comment: I've done this in Selenium--if you're willing to try Selenium instead, just give a holler

Answer (score 1):

I would do it in two phases:

1. a)  save partial data into item 
   b) extract link of the full complaint 
   c) create a new request and save your item into request.meta 
   d) yield request
2. a) extract full complaint 
   b) extract item from meta 
   c) save complaint into item's field 
   d) yield item

   ```
   def parse(self, response):
       hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
       titles = hxs.select('//table[@width="100%"]')
       print titles
       items = []
       del(titles[0])
       for i in titles:
           item = ConsumercomplaintItem()
           item ["maintitle"] = i.select('.//a[1]//text()').extract()
           item ["username"] = i.select('.//td[@class="small"]//a[2]/text()').extract()
           item["date"]=i.select('.//td[@class="small"]/text()').extract()
           item["subtitle"]=i.select('.//td[@class="compl-text"]/div/b[1]/text()').extract()

       complaint_link = row.xpath('//complaint/link/a/@href').extract_first()
       complaint_page = response.urljoin(complaint_link)
       request = scrapy.Request(cve_page, callback=self.parse_complaint)
       request.meta['item'] = item
       yield request

   def parse_complaint(self, response):
       item = response.meta['item']
       item['complaint'] = response.xpath('/complaint/path/text()').extract_first()
       yield item
   ```